# Creating an SQLite table programmatically

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin Forms application. The application contains a button which creates a new list. The list's name and date is saved in one table but the list's contents must be stored in another table, which needs to be created using a **query**. I have been able to successfully insert records into the table that holds the names and dates of the lists using the following approach:

```
[Table("ToDoLists")]
public class ShoppingList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }

    private string _name;

    [NotNull]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    private string _date;

    [NotNull]
    public string Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _date;
        }

        set
        {
            _date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        }
    }

    private string _description;

    [NotNull]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }

        set
        {
            _description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Description));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I have tried the following things:

- Pass on the list name as a table name in the `[Table(tableName)]` statement but the IDE tells me that only constant fields are allowed to be used, meaning that I can't dynamically specify a table name
- I have tried reading about `SQLiteCommand` but the examples I'm given use functions that aren't available in SQLite PCL (unless I've installed SQLite PCL incorrectly).

How exactly do I create a table using a **query** in SQLite PCL? Is it even possible? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net):

> SQLite-net is an open source, minimal library to allow .NET and Mono applications to store data in SQLite 3 databases. It was first designed to work with Xamarin.iOS, but has since grown up to work on all the platforms (Xamarin.*, .NET, UWP, Azure, etc.).
>
> SQLite-net was designed as a quick and convenient database layer. Its
>   design follows from these goals:
>
> - Very easy to integrate with existing projects and runs on all the .NET platforms.
> - Thin wrapper over SQLite that is fast and efficient. (This library should not be the performance bottleneck of your queries.)
> - Very simple methods for executing CRUD operations and queries safely (using parameters) and for retrieving the results of those
>     query in a strongly typed fashion.
> - Works with your data model without forcing you to change your classes. (Contains a small reflection-driven ORM layer.)

First, create a `SQLiteAsyncConnection` to your database:

```
private SQLiteAsyncConnection database; 
database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("YourDatabasePath");
```

Then you can use the method `CreateTableAsync()` to create your table:

```
await database.CreateTableAsync<ShoppingList>();
```

For adding data to the table, you can do something like this:

```
public async Task SaveShoppingObjects(List<ShoppingObjects> shoppingsObjects)
{
    await database.RunInTransactionAsync(tran =>
    {
        foreach (ShoppingObject s in shoppingObjects)
        {
            tran.InsertOrReplace(SqliteEntityFactory.Create(s));
        }
    });
}
```

`SqliteEntityFactory.Create` is a method which helps you creating the table element. It could look something like this:

```
public static ShoppingList Create(ShoppingObject s)
{
    ShoppingList slist = new ShoppingList();
    if (s == null)
    {
        return slist;
    }
    slist.Id = s.Id;
    slist.Name = s.Name;
    // etc...

    return slist;
}
```

If I understand your question right, that should make the trick!

Comment: Thank you! I will look into SQLite Net more closely!